# copy a character array to byte array in capl

Tags: arrays, capl, canoe

i need to copy a character array data into a byte array.
for example :

```
char buffer[20] = "00020406080A0C0E1012";
byte data[10];
```

so, how to copy character array data into a byte array..

please give the solution.
Thank you

Comment: Your `data` variable cannot store all the length of your `buffer` variable

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop:

```
for (i=0;i<elCount(buffer);i++) {
    data[i] = buffer[i];
}
```

Conversion should be automatic.